# Difference between two versions of while loop?

Tags: c++

I have reformulated my question:

I am reading a book in which the author provides the following code sample:

```
while(do_something && i<imax){
   i++;
}
```

Where `do_something` is reading a file: `input_file >> array[amountRead];`

This lead me to wonder why he didn't simply write:

```
while(i<imax){
   do_something;
   i++;
}
```

What is difference in the above two code samples? Is it performance related?

Comment: These are not equivalent, so it's not a fair comparison.

Comment: Is `do_something` a variable or a function call?

Comment: Additionally to them not being equivalent, it is not hard (usually rather trivial) to time the two pieces of code over many executions and determine which is faster.

Comment: Please note that *C* and *C++* are distinct languages and using *C/C++* does not really make sense.

Comment: There's no point in trying to optimize something until you've actually profiled your code and identified that code as a bottleneck. In addition, the code you're trying to compare should do the same thing in different ways, not do two different things altogether. "Which is faster, a Ferrari or an 18-wheel tractor-trailer?" seems to have a clear answer, unless the task is moving 10 tons of freight from point A to point B.

Comment: I am not optimizing anything I am reading a old written code which has the first option and found it interesting but I do not understand why the author of the code wrote it that way.
do_something is reading a file input_file >> array[amountRead];

Comment: No prob. I've tidied up your question - you're already losing downvotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You comment elsewhere:

> do not understand why the author of the code wrote it that way. do_something is reading a file input_file >> array[amountRead];

In that case, the ***functional*** difference is likely much more important than the performance.  The author's existing code is guaranteed to attempt to read at least one element into the array, and further it tests the success of conversions from the stream to the type stored in the array.  The second version *ignores* errors in reading from the stream, both at the binary level and conversion to the array's element type, so it will always tell you `i == imax` at the end regardless of the number of element read.

#### On performance - per your original question

Your first loop always does `do_something` at least once, while the second one tests `i<imax` first and may break without ever doing `do_something`.  In general, the first loop will `do_something` an extra time, which suggests it may be slower if `do_something` is time consuming compared to the looping itself.

But let's make it more interesting... say `imax` is one more for the second loop such that `do_something` is called the same number of times (assuming it was going to run at least once anyway).  The first loop still runs the risk of being slower as it's obliged to consider the results of `do_something` in a boolean context (which in C++ may involve calling a conversion function that could take any amount of time) and conditionally branch before evaluating `i<imax`.

I say only "runs the risk" because given modern CPU execution pipelines the "cost" of that may or may not actually manifest as reduced performance.  If you ever care about performance, benchmark.